# Passing a string value will fail to find the file

Tags: bash

I write a shell which will try to collect a file from the file path into current directory if it exists:

```
collect_file() {
  fpath=$1
  echo $fpath
  if [ -e $fpath ]; then

    fname=`basename $fpath`
    `cp $1 $fname`
    retval=$?
    if [ $retval == 0 ]; then
      echo "Collect file '$fpath'"
    else
      echo "Error: fail to copy file '$fpath'"
    fi

  else
    echo "Error: file '$fpath' not found"
  fi  
}
```

Now, if I pass a bare value `~/.gitconfig`, it will succeed, but when I pass a string value `"~/.gitconfig"`, it will fail.

```
collect_file ~/.gitconfig        # will succeed to copy the file
collect_file "~/.gitconfig"      # will fail
```

Shows:

```
# results for bare value
/Users/Xaree/.gitconfig
Collect file '/Users/Xaree/.gitconfig'

# results for string value
~/.gitconfig
Error: file '~/.gitconfig' not found
```

Why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following refers to a file in the user's home directory:

```
~/.gitconfig
```

By contrast, the following refers to a file in a directory named `~`:

```
"~/.gitconfig"
```

`~/` is interpreted as the home directory when the shell performs *tilde expansion*.  The shell only perform *tilde expansion* when the `!` is unquoted.  If the string is quoted, then `~` just means `~` and nothing else.

#### Examples

Observe that *tilde expansion* is performed for only one of the following three statements:

```
$ echo "~/.bashrc"
~/.bashrc
$ echo ~"/.bashrc"
~/.bashrc
$ echo ~/".bashrc"
/home/john1024/.bashrc
```

#### Forcing a tilde expansion

Tilde expansion, as implemented by the shell, offers many features with many special cases.  We could force a general tilde expansion using `eval` but that would introduce many security issues.  For just the basic case, however, we can safely replace `~/` in a variable with `$HOME/` as follows:

```
fpath="${fpath/~\//$HOME\/}"
```

A problem with the above is that it will do the replace the first occurrence of `~/` even if the string does not start with `~/`.  To avoid that, we can use:

```
[ "${fpath#\~/}" != "$fpath" ] && fpath="${fpath/~\//$HOME\/}"
```

This tests to be sure that the string starts with `~/` before it makes the substitution.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @李岡諭 That the shell suppresses some expansion for quoted strings should generally be considered a feature, not a bug.  But, I just added code to the answer showing how to force simple tilde expansions if you want.